# One app multiple appereances for different customers? (Apple Rules)

Tags: ios, xcode, customization, rules, appearance

Does apple allow apps that change appearance depending on what my servers provides?

For example: I have three customers that use the same app (my app) which is an inventory management system.

It would be kind of unnecessary to create three separate apps, so my idea is that since all inventory management happens remotely on a server, 
I might as well create one app and let them log in to my inventory management system over the internet and supply the app with a layout-file (XML file or whatever) that changes the app appearance depending on who is logged in and which company the user works for.

Is this allowed or is it against Apple guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the typical solution to your problem is [B2B distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) of your app.  In which case you would have multiple versions of the app, but only one version would be available to each company.

Having said that, I do not believe Apple has guidelines against this sort of dynamic branding.  However, the [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) change semi-regularly, so it's always best to [go read them](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) if you have a question.

It's also worth keeping in mind that the guidelines are the "spirit of the law" in that Apple will reject something that doesn't exactly break the rules but breaks what the rules were implying.